# WPF databinding to composite class patterns?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, object, composite

I am trying out WPF for the first time and I am struggling with how to bind controls to a class that is built up using composition of other objects.  For example, If I have class Comp that is built up of two separate classes (note various elements left out for clarity):

```
class One {
   int _first;
   int _second;
}

class Two {
   string _third;
   string _fourth;
}

class Comp {
   int _int1;
   One _part1;
   Two _part2;
}
```

Now I understand that I can easily bind _int1 using a "get" defined in Comp. But how do I bind to the elements _part1._first, _part1._second.  Do I have expose "getters" for them at the class Comp level?  or can I expose them within the composite classes and use a binding path that points to them?  And how does this work with setting the properties?

Thus is this the pattern?

```
....
<TextBlock Name="txtBlock" Text="{Binding Path=Third}" />    
....

class One {
   int _first;
   int _second;
}

class Two {
   string _third;
   string _fourth;
}

class Comp {
   int _int1;
   One _part1;
   Two _part2;

   int Int1 { get { return _int1; } set { _int1 = value; } }
   int First { get { return _part1._first; }  set { _part1._first = value; } }
   int Second { get { return _part1._second; } set { _part1._second = value; } }
   string Third { get { return _part2._third; }  set { _part2._third = value; } }
   string Fourth { get { return _part2.fourth; }  set { _part2._fourth = value; } }
}

...
Comp oComp = new Comp();
txtBlock.DataContext = oComp;
...
```

Or is this the pattern? (where I am not sure what to put for the path)

```
....
<TextBlock Name="txtBlock" Text="{Binding Path=_part2.Third}" />    
....

class One {
   int _first;
   int _second;
   int First { get { return _first; }  set { _first = value; } }
   int Second { get { return _second; }  set { _second = value; } }
}

class Two {
   string _third;
   string _fourth;
   string Third { get { return _third; } set { _third = value; } }
   string Fourth { get { return _fourth; } set { _fourth = value; } }
}

class Comp {
   int _int1;
   One _part1;
   Two _part2;

   int Int1 { get { return _int1; } }
}

...
Comp oComp = new Comp();
txtBlock.DataContext = oComp;
...
```

Or am I on on my way to reinvent M-V-VM (which I am slowly starting to comprehend)?

```
....
<TextBlock Name="txtBlock" Text="{Binding Path=Third}" />    
....

class One {
   int _first;
   int _second;
}

class Two {
   string _third;
   string _fourth;
}

class Comp {
   int _int1;
   One _part1;
   Two _part2;

}

class CompView {
   Comp _comp;

   CompView( Comp comp ) {
      _comp = comp;
   }

   int Int1 { get { return _comp._int1; } set { _comp._int1 = value; } }
   int First { get { return _comp._part1._first; }  set { _comp._part1._first = value; } }
   int Second { get { return _comp._part1._second; } set { _comp._part1._second = value; } }
   string Third { get { return _comp._part2._third; }  set { _comp._part2._third = value; } }
   string Fourth { get { return _comp._part2.fourth; }  set { _comp._part2._fourth = value; } }
 }

...
Comp oComp = new Comp();
CompView oCompView = new CompView( oComp );
txtBlock.DataContext = oCompView;
...
```

So how should I do things?  If it is the first or the third pattern, then it seems that I have take all of my lovely (disparate) hierarchal data and pound it down to a flat configuration so I can bind it to the UI elements.  Is this how it has to happen, or is there a better way (second pattern??)

**Edit**

I left out of the question that I really want two way binding.  So the property accessors really should have get and set.

**Edit**

Updated my pseudo code to show setters as well as getters

**Edit**

I followed through the pattern provided by Mark and Julien and implemented setters and was happy with the result.  For some reason I convinced myself that the setting of a property would not follow all the way down to the final entity.

Comment: this is exactly what i'm stuck on too! thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data Binding works through properties, so you won't use any of the member variables in your Binding, eg:

```
int _first
public int First { get { return _first; } }
```

you'll use First and not _first for the binding.  Normally I've seen each class provide it's own properties to bind to, in which case you could modify your code to:

```
class One : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }

    int _first = 1;
    int _second = 2;
    public int First { get { return _first; }
                       set { _first = value; OnPropertyChanged("First"); } }
    public int Second { get { return _second; }
                        set { _second = value; OnPropertyChanged("Second"); } }
}

class Two : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }

    string _third = "Third";
    string _fourth = "Fourth";
    public string Third { get { return _third; }
                          set { _third = value; OnPropertyChanged("Third"); } }
    public string Fourth { get { return _fourth; }
                           set { _fourth = value; OnPropertyChanged("Fourth"); } }
}

class Comp : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }

    int _int1 = 100;
    One _part1 = new One();
    Two _part2 = new Two();

    public One Part1 { get { return _part1; }
                       set { _part1 = value; OnPropertyChanged("Part1"); } }
    public Two Part2 { get { return _part2; }
                       set { _part2 = value; OnPropertyChanged("Part2"); } }

    public int Int1 { get { return _int1; }
                      set { _int1 = value; OnPropertyChanged("Int1"); } }
}
```

Note that I made the properties public, while keeping the fields defaulted to private.  If you assign the DataContext of a parent control to an instance of Comp:

```
Comp comp = new Comp();
stack.DataContext = comp;
```

You can then bind to the pieces in xaml as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel Name="stack">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Int1}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Part1.First}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Part1.Second}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Part2.Third}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Part2.Fourth}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

here you'll see the StackPanel is given a Comp as the DataContext (and therefore all of it's children also have that DataContext unless another one is specified), and the text is bound to it's member classes.

EDIT: I also added in setters as well as implemented INotifyPropertyChanged which is a vital component to databinding.  With this implemented, you'll be able to bind your data to multiple controls and see the data update in all controls when updated.  You'll need to add:
using System.ComponentModel;

Comment: Ok I can see that .. but (and I'll have to edit my question) .. how does this affect two way binding?  What would a "setter" look like?

Comment: Peter, I added the setters, though I noticed you already added those to your question.  I also implemented INotifyPropertyChanged so you'll be able to bind to multiple controls and keep them in sync.

Answer (score 1):

I think you always have to bind to a property, so your classes should be:

```
class One {
  int _first;
  int _second;
  int First { get { return _first; } }
  int Second { get { return _second; } }
}

class Two {
  string _third;
  string _fourth;
  string Third { get { return _third; } }
  string Fourth { get { return fourth; } }
}

class Comp {
  int _int1;
  One _part1;
  Two _part2;
  One Part1 { get { return _part1; } }
  Two Part2 { get { return _part2; } }
}
```

Then, you should be able to bind to anything yo want:

```
....
<TextBlock Name="txtBlock" Text="{Binding Path=Part2.Third}" />    
....
```

Comment: Neck and neck with Marks answer.  But the winner will be decided by the answer to the question - how do I use two way binding to set the same properties?  :D

Comment: Bindings are automatically two-way if you are using controls that allow editing.  TextBlock is a readonly control. Try a TextBox and see what you get.

Also, you are missing INotifyPropertyChanged implementations here.  You are going to need this so your control knows when your property has changed.

In fact, it really looks like you are moving toward MVVM.  To get a little push in the right direction, try using the MVVMFoundation stuff at http://mvvmfoundation.codeplex.com.  This will help you with a lot of the plumbing code that generally comes with proper MVVM.

Comment: @Anderson I left of a lot of things like INotifyPropertyChanged to try and cut down on the physical size of the post.  I have implemented a test program as per Julien and Mark - which also implemented the setters, and I am happy with that.  But I will take a look at the MVVM link you posted.  Thanks.