# how to bind a datagrid to a custom class object

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

i want to bind a datagrid with a observablecollection of a custom class

lets say i have a class A and class B

```
  Class A
  {
       public B b {get;set;}
       public bool boo {get;set;}
  }
```

and DataGrid as

```
   <DataGrid x:Name="Dg" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="DgCheckBoxColumn" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="30" Binding="{Binding Path=boo, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="False"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Title}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding  Type}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

other values like Id and title are available in class B

Code Behind

```
  ObservableCollection<A> a=new ObservableCollection<A>();
  DgContent.DataContext = a;
```

but it shows empty

if the change the datagrid binding to

```
          Binding="{Binding path=b.Id }"
```

it shows data but also in some other place i bind the same grid to the ObservableCollection of class B and it shows data , so i want to switch between the datacontext for the two objects and show data

is it possible to do it with the same DataGrid?

Comment: Have you tried creating a composite class of A and B, and then binding your data grid to that?

Comment: Check if this link helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200950/wpf-databinding-to-composite-class-patterns

Comment: @Vinkal i think it will only solve the first part of problem, by making the binding to content.Id i wont be able to bind the observablecollection of only class b

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should data bind a public collection property to the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property directly. Then, to data bind to an object within each item, you should simply enter the name of the property that exposes the inner object (in your example that would be `B`) and then the relevant property name of the item. Try this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Dg" ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="DgCheckBoxColumn" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="30" Binding="{Binding B.IsAvailable, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="False"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding B.Id}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding B.Title}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding B.Type}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: it will not be useful when i am keeping the datacontext as a observablecollection of class B, so is it not possible to achieve both things in same datagrid?

Comment: I don't know what you mean.